# Confused about Suspend/resume vm in OpenStack

Tags: instance, state, openstack, resume, suspend

I'm having a problem about suspend/resume instance. Theoretically, as I suspend a vm, it will save the vm's state at that time, and upon resumption, vm is exactly as it was before entering suspending. However, in OpenStack (Juno verrsion), when I resume, it does not return to previous state, which looks like the vm boot from start and requires login username/password. So it make me confused and I don't know why!.

I'm using OpenStack (Juno version), hypervisor is KVM/QEMU.

Thanks all!